# Eigenvalue problem for a one-dimensional electron system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

For a one-dimensional electron system, a simple model has the Hamiltonian:
$$H=\sum_{n=1}^N{E_0|n\rangle\langle{n}|+\sum_{n=1}^N{J[|n\rangle\langle{n+1}|+|n+1\rangle\langle{n}|]}}
$$
where $\langle{n}|n'\rangle=\delta_{nn'}$.$E_0$,$J$ are parameters.Assuming the system has a periodic boundary $|j\rangle=|N+j\rangle$, how to calculate the energy level and wave function?

Comment: Go to momentum space.

Comment: @MengCheng Sorry. I still don't know how to calculate explicitly. I try to use H|j>=E_{j}|j>. But it seems not work

Comment: Do you know Fourier transform? Rewrite your Hamiltonian in the basis $|k\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_i e^{ikj}|j\rangle$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is worked out explicitly on the [Wikipedia page for the tight-binding model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_binding), which indicates to me lack of research effort. In addition, this looks very much like a homework problem where you are not asking about a specific physics concept but rather you are asking how it is to be solved. That is off-topic on this site. Can you re-word your question to ask about a specific physics concept here?

Comment: @march Thanks for your kind suggestion. It's really a homework problem. This is my first problem here, I will not ask the same  useless problem.